# I am facing issue while updating my kali linux, any help? i have pasted terminal's response

Tags: kali-linux

```
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali sana InRelease                                                                                               
Ign:2 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease                                                                          
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:4 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you are way too late in your updating.

Kali 2.0 "sana" is thoroughly obsolete: it has been removed from regular Kali main repository, apparently at sometime in late 2016. No updates have been released for it in years.

[The security.kali.org repository has a README file describing the situation.](http://security.kali.org/kali-security/README) Its timestamp is 2016-09-15:

> This was Kali Linux's security package repository: http://security.kali.org/
>
> With Kali Rolling (2016.x), this repository is no longer needed as security
>   updates come directly from new upstream releases to the Debian Testing
>   distribution.
>
> It was kept alive as long as Kali 2.0 "sana" was available on the main mirror,
>   this is no longer the case and thus this repository is discontinued and will
>   be dropped in the near future.
>
> You can find a backup of the sana/updates repository on old.kali.org if you
>   still need it. The corresponding entry in /etc/apt/sources.list would be:
>
> `deb http://old.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free`

The "near future" mentioned in the README is now in the past, and Kali Sana is no longer present in the Kali main repository. You can see it for yourself by viewing the `dists` directory of the repository with a web browser: http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/

Back in 2016, there might have been a way to update from Kali 2.0 to kali-rolling; but since the latter is a rolling release, it has since then changed a lot, and it is unlikely that the release update procedure from Kali 2.0 to it would have been kept up to date for all these years. I'm afraid that to get fully up to date, you'll need to back up your data and reinstall.

If you change your security repository URL to the old.kali.org URL mentioned above, you will still be able to update your Kali 2.0 installation to the last available level for that release. But since that is the mid-2016 patch level, it is **way out of date** now in terms of security, so it won't help very much.

If you need a stable Linux distribution that has a support lifecycle for more than a year or two, then Kali is an extremely wrong choice for you. If you want to stay with the exact same release for 4 years or more, you should look at the "enterprise"/Long Term Support distributions: for example, RHEL/CentOS, Ubuntu LTS, or SuSE.

Comment: I am new to linux, can you tell me how can I fix this issue. I just want to update linux. I don't care about sana.

Comment: Backup your files, then install a new version of Linux (deleting/overwriting the partition(s) of Kali 2.0), and restore your files from backup. Unfortunately there are no easy ways to update in your situation.